# Why is my onclick event not registered in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, onclick, html-lists

I have a list item with an `onclick` event. It runs in Chrome and Internet Explorer, but not Firefox. Any suggestions?

```
<li onclick="alert('test');">test test<br></li>
```

Comment: Check whether JavaScript is disable in Firefox?

Comment: other javascript events works fine just onclick does not

Comment: you shouldn't be hardcoding your `onclick` events into your html anyways. separate your concerns and wire up your events in a script file.

Comment: Can you please post a complete page showing the problem.

Comment: @hdayi There can be JavaScript Error in you page. Go to the Error Console and Check whether is there any JavaScript error. `Tools --> Web Developer --> Error Console`

Answer (score 4):

This works fine for me in Firefox.

Check this:

1. JavaScript is enabled in your browser.
2. Try adding a `return false;` statement in your tag.

Or a function like this:

```
function test() {
    //your code here
    return false;
}
```

1. Or use this:

`<a href="#" onclick="alert('hi');">Link</a>`

or this

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert('hi');">Link</a>`

Comment: thank you so much. the last suggestion worked. But i could not understand why only onclick event doesn't work. Mousemove, out etc all works. anyway problem solved :)

Comment: I think Firefox needs a return. You may also use a button if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to minimize my html code to send a complete code to simulate the error as Boris Zbarsky requested. Then I found my mistake.

I was using marquee tag which has been deprecated. Now I am going to use jQuery instead of it.

thx

Comment: use https://validator.w3.org/ to prevent strange FF behavior like that.

Answer (score 0):

In [Firefox, the event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) is not global. You have to access it within your script tags not in html.

[`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) works likes this

```
<li id="alert">test<br></li>

<script>
  document.getElementById("alert").addEventListener("click", function( event ) {
    alert('test');
  }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: That's not true and it's no longer relevant to the question.

Comment: @user1133275, how would you write an event listener? Would you write it into the html like originally proposed?

Comment: the example in the question is valid. Which of the valid methods one chooses to use in different contexts is a personal preference and therefore not a good stackoverflow question.... it is good practice to separate languages so limiting all JavaScript to one .js file would be my recommendation even if I don't strictly adhere to it personally.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes can be ignored by Firefox when it is served invalid HTML, use
https://validator.w3.org/
to clean up the HTML.