# Firefox onClick event does not work

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to debug a third party script.

It works fine in Chrome. But Firefox won't register the onclick event.

Any idea why FireFox won't play nice?

I tried adding `return false;` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852165/why-is-my-onclick-event-not-registered-in-firefox) but it did not work, adding that above the very last closing bracket just produces more errors when viewed in console.

```js
 function ac_event(event, eventdata) {
    
    return ajax({
        url: activecampaignevent.ajax_url,
  type: 'POST',
        data: {
   action: 'ac_event',
   event: event,
            eventdata: eventdata
  },
  success: function (response) {
   console.log('response', response);
  }
    });
    
    function ajax(options) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = options.url;
        var data = encodeData(options.data);
        
        if (options.type === 'GET') {
            url = url + (data.length ? '?' + data : '');
        }
        request.open(options.type, options.url, true);
        request.onreadystatechange = onreadystatechange;
        
        if (options.type === 'POST') {
            request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
            request.send(data);
        } else {
            request.send(null);
        }
        return;
        
        function onreadystatechange() {
            if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200){
                options.success(request.responseText);
            }
        }
        function encodeData(data) {
            var query = [];
            for (var key in data) {
                var field = encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]);
                query.push(field);
            }
            return query.join('&');
        }
    }

}
```

```html
<a href="https://somelink.com/" onclick="ac_event('Link Clicked', 'Some Link');">Click this link to test</a>
```

Comment: The code is so old. Why don't you use libraries like jQuery? You never cancel the default event of `<a>` link. Consider using `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @Raptor It's not my code. JavaScript is not my strong point at all. I'm just trying to fix up something that was gifted to me. Can you provide updated code that will fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can create event in javascript and assign it with browser event to stop with preventDefault.

```
document.querySelector("#LinkID").addEventListener("click", function(event){
          //do your code here
            alert("preventDefault will stop you to go")
            event.preventDefault();
        }, false);
```

Comment: Sorry not following you here totally (I'm pretty much brand new to JS). Could you update my code to include your answer?

Comment: check this fiddle after adding return false you code is working in mozilla and chrome http://jsfiddle.net/yogesh078/WQXXT/6551/

Comment: Yes it seems your fiddle does work on Firefox. And with further testing it works with or without the 'return false'. But unfortunately, when using that code on my site it still doesn't register the onclick.