# java script working on firefox offline but not online - working in chrome online

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, tabs, load

So I have a clickable list that loads content based on which item is clicked. It works perfectly in firefox on an offline page. It works perfectly in chrome and IE in an online page.

But in firefox in an online page it only works sometimes, like one 1 in 10 clicks. The default html always loads, tho, and when I click the non-defaults, I can see in the dev tab that firefox requests the appropriate html pages from my server, but somehow the div doesn't always get updated with the selected content. It's as if the '$('#js-content').load(value);' doesn't always activate the new div content.

I really want content that will always work, regardless of browser, browser version, or settings. I have tried a lot of tab example code and all of them broke on one browser or another, this one seemed to work, until I noticed this weird glitch ;(

Can it really be so hard to create tabbed content that works? I see so many professional webpages with tabs and I've never noticed one not working correctly.

update: every time I refresh the page with f5, I can click one tab and the content updates, then it stops updating until I press f5 again. On another machine, with the same firefox 57.0.1 it seems to work fine tho ;(

html:

```
<ul >
   <li id="q1" onClick="LoadSnippet(this.id, 'default.html');">default</li>
   <li id="q2" onClick="LoadSnippet(this.id, 'page2.html');">p1</li>
   <li id="q3" onClick="LoadSnippet(this.id, 'page3.html');">p2</li>
</ul>

<div id="js-content"></div>
```

script:

```
function LoadSnippet(id, value)
{
    id.preventDefault();
    $('#js-content').load(value);
}

// load default tab content.            
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    LoadSnippet("q1", "default.html");        
});
```

Comment: Try removing `id.preventDefault();`.  That is not valid (nor needed) and could be preventing the next line from executing.

Comment: Thanks Justin. The line was actually only added to try and fix the problem, and had no effect ;( I will remove it again, but the problem remains. Any other ideas of things I'm doing that could run into browser incompatibility? Or other ways I could debug this problem with firefox dev tools? (I've pretty much just been looking at the network tab as I'm pretty new to all this. In that tab I see ff asking for the correct pages each time, but I have no idea how to see if it gets it and how it uses it.)

Comment: Maybe your HTML is invalid and FF doesn't like it.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45469853/2012017 and validate that your HTML is not the problem.